# How to schedule a Task to be performed a few minutes later?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I'm working on a Asp.Net core SignalR solution and came across the following problem:

I want the `Hub`'s logic to be able to identify when a user has dropped (e.g. internet connection issues) or the user has wilfully left.

**What I am trying:**

I have 2 user tables in an in-memory db: `Users` and `DroppedUsers`.

The `Hub`is built up of 3 main functions:

- `OnConnectedAsync` - when a user connects, I check if the user is in the `DroppedUsers` DB. If so remove from `DroppedUsers` and add to `Users`.
- `EndSessionAsync` - where the user declares she is now leaving. (adds a `+ LeftAt : DateTime` flag to the user entry in the DB).
- `OnDisconnectedAsync`- removes the user from the DB, if `EndSessionAsync` was called before, otherwise adds the user to a table of dropped users.

I'd like to wait for around 5 mins and see if the user has reconnected.

For example, say the user was added to `DroppedUsers` in the `OnDisconnectedAsync` method, would it be bad practice or dangerous in any way to just put an `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))` before checking again to see if the user is still in `DroppedUsers`?

Below is an example to show the gist of what I mean.

```
...

droppedUsers.Add(user);

await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

if(droppedUsers.Contains(user))
{
    RemoveUser(user);
    DoDisconnectUser(user);
}

...
```

Is there a  more sophisticated way of doing this? I'd like to avoid using an external library.
Also, I don't believe CronJobs are the way to go here. It would add an extra layer of complexity that is unecessary for what I'm trying to achieve.

Lastly, I'm aware a Server crash would mean the method doesn't return from the await. This is not a problem, since the db is in-memory anyway.

Comment: If you're not concerned about a server crash (or more likely an app pool recycle event) your way is perfectly fine. You will probably hear from people insisting this is somehow evil but they won't be able to give you a good reason why. That said I would not init a new task delay in each drop event but rather maintain a single continuous loop that checks for dropped users every few minutes.

Comment: @PeterMoore will the recycle event trigger, while code is executing? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @PeterMoore also, a single loop would be a CronJob at that point. I want each user to have a "grace period" of 5 minutes independent of each other. Also, this is an excpetion. Usually host will end the session. So this would happen only a small amoun tof times. I don't belive it justifies a Background Service (or other type of message loop).

Comment: Recycle can occur any time with IIS. It could be initiated by an admin or other reasons. But you said you're not concerned about that I thought. For the loop no it doesn't need to be a CloudJob. Do an unawaited Task.Run with a while(true) loop. Every minute or so look to see if there are any users that should be removed. You can track times to give them their grace period. I just think a single loop is more scalable. The thread pool isn't infinite.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'll do some tests to work out the  cost-benefit of both approaches. Might post the results here, if there is anything interesting to share.